# MD5 hash of TFileStream is incorrect after write

Tags: delphi, md5

I'm downloading a file using `TIdHttp` and then checking its MD5 hash using `TIdHashMessageDigest5` like this:

```
http := TIdHttp.Create();
fs := TFileStream.Create('mydownload.bin', fmCreate);
md5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;

http.Get(url, fs);
http.Disconnect;

md5Hex := md5.HashStreamAsHex(fs).ToLower;

// expected: 39704b0e2c1d704906d16c42260f45ef
// actual:   d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

However, if I close the `TFileStream` and reopen it, the MD5 is as expected:

```
http := TIdHttp.Create();
fs := TFileStream.Create('mydownload.bin', fmCreate);
md5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;

http.Get(url, fs);
http.Disconnect;

fs.Free;
fs := TFileStream.Create('mydownload.bin', fmOpenRead);

md5Hex := md5.HashStreamAsHex(fs).ToLower;

// expected: 39704b0e2c1d704906d16c42260f45ef
// actual:   39704b0e2c1d704906d16c42260f45ef
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you try to set the Position the Filestream to 0 before calculating the md5?

Comment: @PhilippH. That solved the problem! If you want to provide it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Position of the Filestream needs to be set to zero before calculating the hash.

The code should look like this.

```
http := TIdHttp.Create();
fs := TFileStream.Create('mydownload.bin', fmCreate);
md5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;

http.Get(url, fs);
http.Disconnect;

fs.Position := 0;
md5Hex := md5.HashStreamAsHex(fs).ToLower;
```